# Is there an equivalent way to set up a mock implementation instead of the __mocks__ directory approach with jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a utility function called `retry` that wraps a passed function with some retry logic (simplified version below).

In some tests, I want to just call the passed function once instead of doing the retry logic.

```js
app/retry.js

module.exports = async function retry(funcProvider) {
    let retriesLeft = 5;

    while (retriesLeft > 0) {
      try {
        return await funcProvider();
      } catch (error) {
        // delay for a bit

        retriesLeft--;
      }
    }
};
```

and the equivalent `__mocks__` version.

```
app/__mocks__/retry.js

module.exports = async function retry(funcProvider) {
  return await funcProvider();
}
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent to above but without using the `__mocks__` setup? I'd like to do this inline in the test file using something like the factory param of `jest.mock()` (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), but I can't figure out the right combination. Wondering if I'm missing something obvious or if this is a "limitation" of jest. Note that I need to reference the passed argument in the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jest.mock('app/retry.js', () => 
  async (funcProvider) => { return await funcProvider(); }
);
```

Also you may use `__mocks__` and also modify mock if you need(since it's already the same jest's mock object):

```
import retryMock from 'app/retry';

....
it('....', () => {
  retryMock.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject());
```